# Cómo evitar reset dropdown-menu después de history back Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente dropdown-menu y necesito saber cómo puedo conservar el valor seleccionado después de volver a la página mediante un history back.

```
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                            <li class='active' onclick='per_page(15);' id='15'><a href="#">15</a></li>
                            <li onclick='per_page(25);' id='25'><a href="#">25</a></li>
                            <li onclick='per_page(50);' id='50'><a href="#">50</a></li>
                            <li onclick='per_page(100);' id='100'><a href="#">100</a></li>
                            <li onclick='per_page(1000000);' id='1000000'><a href="#">Todos</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: has pensado/probado a utilizar localStorage?

Comment: no lo he pensado, porque no manejo mucho el tema.

Answer (score 0):

una opcion como te comentaba es utilizar el localStorage, que almacenara el valor en el navegador, si solo quieres utilizar ese valor mientras no cierre el navegador puedes utilizas sessionStorage que se borrara cuando se cierre el navegador.

en tu funcion

```
> per_page(value)
```

le agregas el guardado en localStorage o sessionStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('limit', value.toString());
```

donde 'limit' es el nombre de la clave,  y 'value' el valor que tiene esa clave

para recuperar el valor simplemente:

```
var limit = localStorage.getItem('limit');
```

y solo te quedaria comprobar si la variable limit contiene un valor para asignarlo a tu fincion de carga de datos:

```
if(limit){...asigna el valor de limit...}else{..valor por defecto..}
```

espero esto te ayude